# evaluate this definite integral $\int_{-2}^{2} \frac{x^2}{(1+5^x)}dx$ ??

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

$$\int_{-2}^{2} \frac{x^2}{(1+5^x)}dx$$
I tried taking the substitution of $$1+5^x = u$$ in hope i will get product of two functions which can be integrated by parts but it turns out to be a very complicated function. Is it possible to integrate it using some property of definite integral?

Comment: Do $y=-x$, add the two integrals you have, see the magic happen.

Comment: Unfortunately $\int\frac{x^2}{1+5^x}dx$ is not an elementary function

Comment: i am stil unable to solve after adding can mickep please elaborate

Comment: This question was asked earlier today...